# Magento WYSIWYG editor losing input

Tags: magento, wysiwyg

I've recently upgraded Magento CE from 1.8 to 1.9

When editing a CMS page, if I paste any data and save, when I got back and edit that page, my pasted text has disappeared. By disabling the Magento WYSIWYG editor, it seems fine, but of course, I can then only enter raw HTML.

This only seems to have happened since upgrading to 1.9. I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when copying content from MS Word into the Redactor WYSIWYG extension for Magento 1.9 CE.

I've made a very simply/ugly fix and it seems to work a treat. I've rewrote the StripTags function around `line 1282` in the redactor.js file in: `/skin/adminhtml/default/default/mgt_amazing_wysiwyg/js/redactor`

Here's my rewrote function:

```
// REMOVE TAGS
stripTags: function(html)
{

  // Redactor WYSIWYG editor refusing to accept pasted content from MS Word
  // By Kingsley Raspe
  // See: https://gist.github.com/kingsloi/97260c320bf22e5b96c7
  var allowedObj = this.opts.allowedTags;
  var allowed = '';

    //convert allowedTags to string in <b><i><h1> format
    for (var p in allowedObj) {
      if (allowedObj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        allowed += '<' + allowedObj[p] + '>';
      }
    }

    //search and destroy
    allowed = (((allowed || "") + "").toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join('');
    var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
    commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
    return html.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function($0, $1){
      return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
    });

},
```

Bit late I know, but I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can edit /magento/js/tiny_mce/classes/Editor.js in line 101 from "named"

```
// entity_encoding : 'named'
entity_encoding : 'raw'
```